# Excel macro to copy entire row to a new worksheet based on the value of a 'category' column

Tags: vba

I have what I think is a fairly simple requirement but am having trouble implementing.  I have tried copying and modifying various bits of vba code I have researched but none seem to work for me.

I have a spreadsheet which is basically a name and address list.  I have a column called category which I want to be able to use to populate new (if they don't exist and append if they do) worksheets.

Imagine I had 4 customers - two with a category of London, 1 for Manchester and 1 for Liverpool.  These are in the 'master' worksheet.

I would like to run a marco that created or appended to worksheets called London, Manchester and Liverpool and copied the corresponding rows to the relevant worksheet and sorted alphabetically.

I do hope someone can help me.

thanks

Paul

Comment: What have you tried (provide your code)? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error message and what line does it error on?  If it doesn't error, what does the code result in and how does that differ from expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you have in the "Master" worksheet are 3 columns: Name | Address | Category and this Header will be copied across to Category named sheets.

Then `PopulateMasterContacts` will process the rows in Master and put into worksheet that is named Category. If this named worksheet is not found, it will create one and copy the header, then the contact detail. And sort all the worksheets except the Master.  Please note this will not remove duplicates.

```
Private Const sMasterSheet As String = "Master" ' Master Sheet Name

Private Const lNameCol As Long = 1 ' Coulmn A
Private Const lAddrCol As Long = 2 ' Column B
'Private Const lCateCol As Long = 3 ' Column C
Private Const lCateCol As Long = 16 ' Column P

Dim oShM As Worksheet ' For Master Worksheet

Sub PopulateMasterContacts()
    Const lRowStart As Long = 2
    Dim lRowM As Long, lRowLast As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oShM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sMasterSheet)
    lRowLast = oShM.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    For lRowM = lRowStart To lRowLast
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing row " & lRowM
        If Not IsEmpty(oShM.Cells(lRowM, lNameCol)) Then
            ProcessContact lRowM
        End If
    Next
    SortSheets
    Set oShM = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub SortSheets()
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    For Each oSh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If oSh.Name <> sMasterSheet Then
            oSh.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=oSh.Cells(2, lNameCol), Header:=xlYes
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessContact(lR As Long)
    Dim sCategory As String, lRowNext As Long, oSh As Worksheet
    sCategory = oShM.Cells(lR, lCateCol).Value
    If Len(sCategory) > 0 Then
        Set oSh = GetWorksheet(sCategory)
        lRowNext = oSh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1
        lRowNext = oSh.Cells(lRowNext, lNameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        oShM.Rows(lR).Copy Destination:=oSh.Rows(lRowNext)
        Set oSh = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetWorksheet(sName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName)
    If oSh Is Nothing Then
        Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=oShM)
        oSh.Name = sName
        oShM.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=oSh.Rows(1) ' Copy header
    End If
    Set GetWorksheet = oSh
End Function
```

Updated Screenshots:
[image]

Which row it shows when the error comes up in the Status bar?
[image]

Comment: Patrick - that worked a treat.  My actual sheet contains many more columns so I have tried to amend your script but get a subscript out of line error. I did some further playing and found that it works as long as category col is is col 3 but my category is actually in col P.

Comment: I've tried to post my code in this comment but it is too long

Comment: I have revised the code to use Column P as the Category column. Have another go. The constant you needed to change is `lCateCol`.

Comment: Hi - I get a run time error 9 - subscript out of range error now.  Was trying to debug to see what line this caused a problem on but not had much luck as yet.

Comment: I spotted a typo above for lNameCol and corrected but still the same error. Makes no difference to the error.  Do I have to declare all the columns I am using or just the ones that are used in functions?

Comment: Is there any way I can copy first 2 headers before copying the data. I need to make changes in the code to consider first 2 columns as headers.

Comment: @Striker I assume you mean first 2 rows of headers: change `oShM.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=oSh.Rows(1) ' Copy header` to `oShM.Rows("1:2").Copy Destination:=oSh.Rows(1) ' Copy header` and `Const lRowStart As Long = 2` to `Const lRowStart As Long = 3`.

Comment: That worked! Also I want to group each worksheet which is created from column D:AM? I tried but I am not able to achieve the desired result in each sheet properly.